# How to handle many concurrently interacting entities in C#

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I am developing an application that has many different entities that can interact concurrently. I'm wondering what the best way is for those entities to interact with each other in a thread safe way.

To demonstrate with some simplified code, consider that each entity has it's own fiber and some state:

```
class Fiber
{
    private ActionBlock<Action> _workQueue;

    public Fiber()
    {
        _workQueue = new ActionBlock<Action>((a) => a());
    }

    public void Enqueue(Action a)
    {
        _workQueue.Post(a);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _workQueue.Complete();
    }
}

class EntityState
{
    public int x { get; set; }
}

class Entity
{
    private Fiber _fiber = new Fiber();

    public EntityState State { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Assume actions are arbitrarily enqueued onto an entities fiber. One such action may be that an entity must modify another entity's state. There are two options I've considered to do this in a thread safe way.

Option 1: Only allow state mutation through a thread-safe wrapper, I.E.

```
class Entity
{
    private Fiber _fiber = new Fiber();

    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _stateLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private EntityState _state = new EntityState();

    public T ReadState<T>(Func<EntityState, T> reader)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        _stateLock.EnterReadLock();
        result = reader(_state);
        _stateLock.ExitReadLock();

        return result;
    }

    public void WriteState(Action<EntityState> writer)
    {
        _stateLock.EnterWriteLock();
        writer(_state);
        _stateLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Option 2: Only allow state mutation by scheduling it onto the owning entity's fiber and return a Future so that the mutator can see when the mutation has taken place, I.E.

```
class Future<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

class Entity
{
    private Fiber _fiber = new Fiber();

    private EntityState _state = new EntityState();

    public Future<T> AccessState<T>(Func<EntityState, T> accessor)
    {
        Future<T> future = new Future<T>();

        _fiber.Enqueue(() => future.Value = accessor(_state));

        return future;
    }

    // ...
}
```

What other options haven't I considered? Is there a good way to do this? Should I be doing this at all?

Answer (score 1):

All of your options are going to bring pain to you.

1. Even if the code would be technically correct, you'll experience logical race condition in your domain. Something like order could be shipped before it paid.
2. It hurts maintainability. Threading code is hard to debug, hard to test, hard to read. When it's interleaved with application this gets much more complicated.

The right way is to separate threading code from application code completely. Put tasks in a single-threaded fiber. A task performs all jobs synchronously across all involved entities. After the task finished, you can perform IO asynchronously. 
I've written [a library](https://github.com/Codestellation/DarkFlow) for such approach.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Both of your points are absolutely right and I'm already starting to feel like writing code is like walking through a field of land mines ;). The project is a game server, which is why I've gone for high concurrency. I'm aiming to run updates ever 50ms, so updating each entity synchronously is really going to hurt performance. It's important that other entities aren't  affected if one entity has a slow update.

Answer (score 1):

You could enqueue the mutation into the owning Fiber, then enqueue the continuation of that to your own fiber. That way you don't have any explicit locks.

But: this Fiber approach is not better than just taking a `lock` before accessing an entity. (The lock contains a queue internally.)

Also, you cannot have cross-entity transactions this way. With the locks approach, you can collect the locks of all entities participating in a transaction, sort them into a total order and lock them all. That gives you cross-entity transactions without deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm more or less doing as you mentioned (see my answer). I'm using the fiber because each entity receives data from a network stream using async sockets. I schedule them onto a fiber to ensure they're handled in order that they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I ended up going with option 2 more or less, but I set the result synchronously if accessing the state won't block. I.E.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server.Utility
{
    public class ThreadSafeWrapper<ObjectType>
    {
        private ObjectType m_object;
        private Fiber m_fiber;

        public ThreadSafeWrapper(ObjectType obj, Fiber fiber)
        {
            m_object = obj;
            m_fiber = fiber;
        }

        public Future<ReturnType> Transaction<ReturnType>(Func<ObjectType, ReturnType> accessor)
        {
            Future<ReturnType> future = new Future<ReturnType>();

            ReturnType synchronousResult = default(ReturnType);
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(m_object))
            {
                synchronousResult = accessor(m_object);
                Monitor.Exit(m_object);

                future.SetResult(synchronousResult);
            }
            else
            {
                m_fiber.Enqueue(() =>
                {
                    ReturnType result = default(ReturnType);
                    lock (m_object)
                    {
                        result = accessor(m_object);
                    }
                    future.SetResult(result);
                });
            }

            return future;
        }

        public void Transaction(Action<ObjectType> accessor)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(m_object))
            {
                accessor(m_object);
                Monitor.Exit(m_object);
            }
            else
            {
                m_fiber.Enqueue(() =>
                {
                    lock (m_object)
                    {
                        accessor(m_object);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```